# Which python 3.x is good for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04

As Python 2.7 is going to end by end of this year,so i am thinking to upgrade my project to 3.x which is to be use in ubuntu 14.04. So i am confused about which python 3.x will be good for it. Can any one suggest me that which python 3.x should i use for ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Get the most current 3.x you can get. In order to upgrade your python projects, you will have to do a series of testing yourself and change your code to work on the 3.x version you choose.

Comment: can you tell me that between 3.6 and 3.7 which one is good.

Comment: Go with 3.7 if you can. See https://realpython.com/python37-new-features/

Comment: so according to you it's does not matter which os you are using right??

Comment: From my perspective, OS doesn't really matter that much. Choice of OS depends on various business requirements. My preference would be GNU/Linux (latest Ubuntu LTS). I don't which version of Python is supported on 14.04. If you can install 3.7, I'd go with 3.7.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Beside of the funky stuff provided in realpython.com/python37-new-features , is there any major difference between 3.6 and 3.7

Comment: For day to day use, I find no difference between 3.6 and 3.7.

Comment: just a quick question. is python 3.6 compatible with ubntu 14.04??

Comment: I don't know. You'll have to find which the highest version of python is that's compatible with 14.04